# Android: How to get SIM-ID of both SIMs in Android?

Tags: android

I want to get unique id for SIM (`line1number` or `simserialnumber`...) when SMS is received. It works fine for single SIM. Is it possible for multi SIM?

Comment: Please post your code so that some one can help you better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple SIM support was only added to the standard Android API in Android 5.1 (Lollipop_MR1 - API Level 22) - see [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.1.html#multisim). Devices earlier than that with multiple SIMs used customised versions of Android to support multiple SIMs, so there's no standard way to get the information you want as it will work differently on each device.

If you're targeting API Level 22 and above, you can use [SubscriptionManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionManager.html) to get the information about different SIMs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can use the `SubscriptionManager` to get the subscription information.

Also note that we have a `Parcelable` class for Subscription Information called `SubscriptionInfo` that has following method relevant to you:

```
public int getSimSlotIndex ()
public int getSubscriptionId ()
```